# In bibtex where exactly proceeding keyword should appear in booktitle?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I was told that when copying bibtex ref for conference citations from dblp or ACM or ... not directly copy it, but modify it and make it consistent!
 In bibtex *@inproceedings* I am not sure where to put the keyword "proceeding"? In dblp booktitle sometimes ***proceedings*** keyword comes in the beginning, sometimes in the end. Which one is recommended? and why is like that?

For eg here Proceedings is appeared in the end of booktitle:

```
    @inproceedings{DBLP:conf/cav/Shtrichman00,
    ...
    booktitle = {Computer Aided Verification, 12th International Conference, CAV, **Proceedings**},
    series    = {Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
    volume    = {1855},
    pages     = {480--494},
    publisher = {Springer},
    year      = {2000},
    }
```

Comment: Judging by the appearance of the book cover at https://www.amazon.com/Computer-Aided-Verification-International-Proceedings/dp/3540677704/ref=sr_1_fkmrnull_1?keywords=Computer+Aided+Verification%2C+12th+International+Conference+springer&qid=1554235471&s=gateway&sr=8-1-fkmrnull#reader_3540677704, I'd say that placing the string "Proceedings" at the very end of the `booktitle` field is correct -- at least for this particular entry. Other publishers may have other conventions.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's helpful to call the word "Proceedings" a *keyword*. For sure, you should spend most of your efforts to make sure that the information contained in the various fields of a bibliographic entry are *factually correct*. Where the word "Proceedings" might show up inside the `booktitle` field is not a particularly pressing issue.